# WOPI Host implementation issues

Tags: ms-wopi

We’re trying to implement a Wopi Host following the protocol to integrate with OWA, as documented in [here](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and we’re having some issues with some points:

- We have implemented a simple host that is only capable of viewing files, that is, it implements the CheckFileInfo and GetFile views. In a test environment, the flow is working and we’re able to view the files in OWA. The point is, when executing the Wopi Validator (the web and the docker version), we’re having an error in the GetFile operation because the validator is trying to access the endpoint with two // at the end:

  `host/wopi/files/file_id//contents`

  Is this a known issue that is happening only in the validator? Why are the two ‘/’ being appended to the end of the WopiSrc? How can we address this issue?
- We have read some posts here stating that the editing is required in order to officially validate our OWA integration with Microsoft. Is this true? Isn’t the CheckFileInfo and GetFile views the only ones necessary to implement a simple Wopi host capable only of viewing files? We’re just passing the required information in the response of the CheckFileInfo operation. We’re not using FileUrl or any other parameter but the required ones. As far as I can see, these two views are the only one required for viewing files with OWA, such as stated [here](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wopi_requirements.html#requirements)
- Additionally, we’re having an issue in the first part of the flow, when the browser sends a request to OWA and passes the token and the WopiSrc. We were only able to make the flow work passing the token in the query string via the GET method. If we put it under a JSON with a POST method, the OWA simply ignores it and does not make an attempt to call the Wopi Host at all, via the WopiSrc. Could someone enlighten us a bit on this matter to figure out what may be happening?
- Furthermore, we’re stuck in some point of token validation. The docs are crystal clear when they say that the token is generated by the host, and that it should be unique for a single user/file combination. We have done that. The problem is, how are we supposed to know what is the user that is trying to access a resource, when the request comes from OWA? For example, when the OWA calls the host in the CheckFileInfo and GetFile views, it passes us the token. But how could we know the user information as well? Since the token is for a single file (which we have in the address of the endpoint being accessed) and for a single user, how can we validate the user at this point? We have not found any header or placeholder value that could be used to extract this information when receiving a request from OWA, and we’re a bit lost here. We’ve thought about appending the user information to the token, and then extracting it back, but for what I could see, doing that I’m only ensuring that the token has not been modified between requests. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the validation with Microsfot demands the edit functionality.

For the POST situation, the submission must be made as a "form" not as JSON.

The token validation is completely open, you must choose the way you think would be the best approach. JWT is a good alternative in this case.